# How to fix this error: Msg 50000, Level 17, State 2, Procedure tSQLt.FakeTable, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 0] Please run this inside a unit test

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

I am currently working on my SQL Server project unit testing using TSQLT and I'm getting the below error, and don't know how to fix it.

Has anyone faced it before? Can anyone suggest a tutorial for TSQLT?

> Msg 50000, Level 17, State 2, Procedure tSQLt.FakeTable, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Please run this inside a unit test

Comment: Show the stored procedure code.  This is very likely a custom error.

Comment: tSQLt runs unit tests inside transactions so that changes made during unit tests are not persisted. Are you trying to execute `tSQLt.FakeTable` outside of `tSQLt.Run`, or specifically outside of a transaction?

Comment: There is a QuickStart guide on tSQLt.org.       (https://tsqlt.org/user-guide/)

Answer (score 1):

In tSQLt, tests are written as stored procedures that live in test classes. As such one might be tempted to just execute those stored procedures. However, a lot of the tSQLt functionality relies on being executed as part of a controlled test run. Directly executing test stored procedures can leave the database in an undesirable state.

Therefore it is important to always use `tSQLt.Run` or `tSQLt.RunAll` to execute your tests.

Comment: is that new functionality?

Comment: This error is part of one of a pull requests that has not been approved. I assume the OP got a version with that enabled from somewhere. But the more important part is that you don’t want to run your test procedures directly - independently of that causing this error or other symptoms. :)

Comment: I definitely know that, just was surprised that he got such error :)